# How do I add API Endpoints in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, endpoints

I would like to register API Endpoints in ASP.NET by just adding few methods in **ApiController**. A new method there means a new API.

In a random example below:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
```

needs to serve the following Endpoints:

```
/
/price
/price/discount
```

Problem here is all endpoints are having a GET request to /, and result in same output as /.

[Reference URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) and [Service Contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-endpoint-in-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place Route annotation at method for which you want to use custom route.

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    // this will be called on GET /Customers or api/Customers can't remember what default
    //config is
    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        ...
    }

    // this will be called on GET /My/Route/Customers
    [HttpGet, Route("My/Route/Customers)]
    public List<Customer> GetCustomersFromMyRoute()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```